# Limit headers to range, if-match in Caddyfile

Tags: server, http-headers, caddy, caddyfile

I would like to prevent downloading of my whole file that has several gigabytes by users and allow only range requests, something in this fashion (this is taken from Cloudflare I think):

```
"AllowedOrigins": ["https://example.com"],
"AllowedMethods": ["GET","HEAD"],
"AllowedHeaders": ["range","if-match"], // <-- I am interested in this
"ExposeHeaders": ["etag"],
"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
```

I am mostly interested in AllowedHeaders and how to do that in my Caddyfile (the other ones are just bonus if you know it you could mention it.

How can I write the same allow headers but in the syntax of Caddy?